# Apache error: _default_ virtualhost overlap on port 443

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I get this error when trying to start Apache.

> _default_ virtualhost overlap on port 443

I'm trying to set up SSL. Almost every solution online says add:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

to the conf file but Apache still fails to start and just says

> Action start failed. the apache logs may have more information

There is zero information in the Apache logs.

Comment: Which logs are you checking? If you're on a Linux system, run `netstat –lp --inet` to see if some process is already running and using port 443.

Comment: nope nothing else is using port 443. the problem is the conflict between my settings for <VirtualHost _default_:443> and <VirtualHost *:443>....

Comment: Note: I had put the `NameVirtualHost` bit inside an `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` section - seemed sensible - but it must be outside that.

Comment: [In 2.3.11 and later](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost), any time an IP address and port combination is used in multiple virtual hosts, name-based virtual hosting is automatically enabled for that address.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

To resolve the issue on a Debian/Ubuntu system modify the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` settings file by adding `NameVirtualHost *:443` to it. My `ports.conf` is the following at the moment:

```
# /etc/apache/ports.conf
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.

    NameVirtualHost *:443

    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Furthermore ensure that **'sites-available/default-ssl'** is not enabled, type `a2dissite default-ssl` to disable the site. While you're at it type `a2dissite` by itself to get a list and see if there is any other site settings that you have enabled that might be mapping onto port 443.

Comment: HI @MUYBelgium, that means there is another vhost that maps onto 443 port. Take a look in `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/` or on Debian/Ubuntu disable all sites with `a2dissite` and enable them back one by one with `a2ensite` until error appears; hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah... I had same issue. Had to update ports.conf AND sites-avaialble/default-ssl (to replace _default_ with *) THEN I could enable my other virtual hosts with SSL. Should edit your answer to include this additional information.

Comment: Thank you very much, adding NameVirtualHost *:443 fixed the problem! Users, please note that in modern Debian/Ubuntu with Apache2 the file is /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Comment: that's apache2.2;  [In 2.3.11 and later](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost), any time an IP address and port combination is used in multiple virtual hosts, name-based virtual hosting is automatically enabled for that address.

This directive currently has no effect.

Comment: Do you even need the default-ssl file? Can I just clear the contents?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin You don't need it, but I'd leave it in and just disable the site.

Comment: Worked for me!  I had the `NameVirtualHost *:80` at the top but I did not have the `NameVirtualHost *:443` in either of the other 2 places.  Adding it fixed my issues.

Comment: Just so every one knows, `NameVirtualHost` is deprecated since apache httpd 2.3.11 - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

Answer (score 33):

On a vanilla Apache2 install in CentOS, when you install mod_ssl it will automatically add a configuration file in:

```
{apache_dir}/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

This configuration file contains a default virtual host definition for port 443, named *default*:443. If you also have your own virtual host definition for 443 (i.e. in httpd.conf) then you will have a confict. Since the conf.d files are included first, they will win over yours.

To solve the conflict you can either remove the virtual host definition from `conf.d/ssl.conf` or update it to your own settings.

Comment: This was was the source of the error for me on CentOS and also helped explain the warning indicating that ssl_mod could not loaded twice.

Comment: Thanks for this, I struggled a bit to decode your answer.
Comment out everything from the line <Virtualhost _default_:443> to line </Virtualhost> in ssl.conf for it to work.

Comment: That makes sense -- for a single VH. I have hundreds in httpd.conf and I want to apply SSL to them all. If I remove the _default_:443 in ssl.conf, I will then have to put all the commands from it into _every_ VH definition in httpd.conf, which is going to be overkill, surely.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was banging my head over trying to figure out why my aliased location directives were not being redirected to port 443! Sho' nuff, this was the issue.

Comment: Exactly what's happening to me. Saved my day :). I endup just rename the `ssl.conf` file to `ssl.conf-dackup`

Answer (score 13):

It is highly unlikely that adding `NameVirtualHost *:443` is the right solution, because there are a limited number of situations in which it is possible to support name-based virtual hosts over SSL. Read [this](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Apache2/SSL_and_Name_Based_Virtual_Hosts) and [this](http://www.geekwisdom.com/dyn/node/215) for some details (there may be better docs out there; these were just ones I found that discuss the issue in detail).

If you're running a relatively stock Apache configuration, you probably have this somewhere:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

Your best bet is to either:

- Place your additional SSL configuration into this existing `VirtualHost` container, or
- Comment out this entire `VirtualHost` block and create a new one.  Don't forget to include all the relevant SSL options.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion but i still cant get apache to work. theres a default-ssl file in /etc/apache2/sites-available which contains <VirtualHost _default_:443> and when i create a new file in /etc/apache2/sites-available for mydomain.com and include the SSL setting for <VirtualHost *:443>, I get the _default_ vhost overlap on port 443 error. when i just have the default-ssl with my new SSL settings, i just get an action start failed when i try to start apache with nothing in the error logs...im completely tuck:(

Comment: after generating the ssl again and putting <VirtualHost _default_:443> into the pache2.conf file, apache is starting again and ssl i sworking:)

Comment: "With Apache 2.2.12 and support for the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to the SSL protocol, you can configure name-based HTTPS sites, just as you can name-based HTTP sites." (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/configure-apache-to-support-multiple-ssl-sites-on-a-single-ip-address/987) - only old versions of Internet Explorer may give you a headache with multiple host names on one IP address when using SSL...

Comment: What if I commented it out and I still get this message when I restart Apache? `grep -r _default_ /etc/httpd/` only turns up the vhost I commented out. Does Apache cache config files?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem because I had multiple wildcard entries for the same ports. You can easily check this by executing `apache2ctl -S`:

```
# apache2ctl -S
[Wed Oct 22 18:02:18 2014] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 30000, the first has precedence
[Wed Oct 22 18:02:18 2014] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 20001, the first has precedence
VirtualHost configuration:
11.22.33.44:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server xxx.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xxx.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost xxx.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xxx.com.conf:1)
         [...]
11.22.33.44:443      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server yyy.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yyy.com.conf:37)
         port 443 namevhost yyy.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yyy.com.conf:37)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   hostname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
*:20001                hostname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:33)
*:30000                hostname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:57)
_default_:443          hostname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
*:20001                hostname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:163)
*:30000                hostname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:178)
Syntax OK
```

Notice how at the beginning of the output are a couple of warning lines. These will indicate which ports are creating the problems (however you probably already knew that).

Next, look at the end of the output and you can see exactly which files and lines the virtualhosts are defined that are creating the problem. In the above example, port 20001 is assigned both in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` on line 33 and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl` on line 163. Likewise `*:30000` is listed in 2 places. The solution (in my case) was simply to delete one of the entries.

Comment: Yep, this helped a lot. I had a sample www.example.com entry on 443 causing all my other 443 virtual hosts to emit errors.