# Virtual Host Config Issue? (80, 443, 8080)

Tags: apache, port, virtualhost

I have an issue I can not seem to get around.  I setup apache 2.2 with SSL and it works like a charm.  I have it redirecting to SSL with out issues as well.

The java application that runs on the server uses port 8080.

I created a virtual host (below), but now my SSL does not work.  Even if I type "https://hostname/application/etc.jsp" it will go to a can not display screen.
NOTE: If I type in "http://hostname/application/etc.jsp" (non-ssl), the page comes up fine.

I also tried <"VirtualHost *:80 *:443"> and still no good. <", I know the " is not supposed to be there, but this post will not show anything in the <...> if I do not put it there!

```
<"VirtualHost *:80">                           
ServerName Dev-AppSrv
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    LogLevel warn
    keepalive Off
    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

    ProxyPass /learning/ http://Dev-AppSrv:8080/learning/ disablereuse=on retry=0

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyTimeout 1200
    ProxyPass /plateau/ http://Dev-AppSrv:8080/plateau/ disablereuse=on retry=0
    ProxyPass /help/ http://Dev-AppSrv:8080/help/ disablereuse=on retry=0
    ProxyPass /pqe/ http://Dev-AppSrv:8080/pqe/ disablereuse=on retry=0

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache error: \_default\_ virtualhost overlap on port 443](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658017/apache-error-default-virtualhost-overlap-on-port-443)