# Apache multiple domains on a same IP and port

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I tried to follow the documentation of Apache on "[Running several name-based web sites on a single IP address](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#purename)." but reached a dead end. I want to have two websites (example1.com and example2.com) running on the Same IP address on Port 80. But example1.com has also a secured version running on 443. Therefore, the virtualhost of example1.com:80 has a permanent redirect to example1.com:443. All combinations of settings that I tried either cause me to only access example1.com:443 or crash the server. The current running configuration is as follows:

```
Listen 1.1.1.1:80
Listen 1.1.1.1:443

NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
  DocumentRoot /www/root2
  ServerName example2.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
  ServerName example1.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example1.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
  DocumentRoot /www/root1
  ServerName www.example1.com
  SSLEngine on
  # Certificate paths
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas on what the correct configuration should be to run it in the needed requirement.

Comment: You need to `NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443` too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache error: \_default\_ virtualhost overlap on port 443](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658017/apache-error-default-virtualhost-overlap-on-port-443)

Comment: I want to do the similar thing but i need both domains secure. @Sami can you please share your findings with me?
In my case i have sub-domain say example.com & sub.example.com.

Comment: I couldn't find an answer so far as everything I tried caused the access to an SSL page or a crash.